# Pyarrow Table doesn't seem to have to_pylist() as a method

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pyarrow

pyarrow documentation says that the `Table` class has a method called `to_pylist` which should return a list of dictionaries.

https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.Table.html#pyarrow.Table.to_pylist

When I run their code example:

```py
import pyarrow as pa
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'n_legs': [2, 4, 5, 100],
                   'animals': ["Flamingo", "Horse", "Brittle stars", "Centipede"]})
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
table.to_pylist()
```

I get the following `attributeerror`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'pyarrow.lib.Table' object has no attribute 'to_pylist'
```

Has `to_pylist` been removed or is there something wrong with my package?

Comment: Which version of pyarrow are you using?

Comment: ah I'm on 6.0.0 where it's not available cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method `to_pylist` was added to `pa.Table` in version 7.0.0. As suggested, could you check that the version of `pyarrow` you are using is not older?