# Polars to_dicts() fails but other methods work

Tags: python, python-polars

I'm trying to rename columns in a polars DataFrame.  Following very useful advice in this question:
[How to rename column names with first row in polars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75187317/how-to-rename-column-names-with-first-row-in-polars)

I've attempted to use to_dicts on a dataframe my_df.

```
my_df.head(1).to_dicts()
```

This fails with the message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\polars\dataframe\frame.py", line 1973, in to_dicts
    return list(self.iter_rows(named=True))
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\polars\dataframe\frame.py", line 8383, in iter_rows
    yield from zerocopy_slice.to_arrow().to_pylist()
AttributeError: 'pyarrow.lib.Table' object has no attribute 'to_pylist'
>>> import pyarrow
>>> df_addr_parsed2.head(1).to_dicts()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\polars\dataframe\frame.py", line 1973, in to_dicts
    return list(self.iter_rows(named=True))
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\polars\dataframe\frame.py", line 8383, in iter_rows
    yield from zerocopy_slice.to_arrow().to_pylist()
AttributeError: 'pyarrow.lib.Table' object has no attribute 'to_pylist'
```

Following this question: [How to resolve "ImportError: DLL load failed:" on Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41365446/how-to-resolve-importerror-dll-load-failed-on-python)

I tried using `os.add_dll_directory()`, which did make a difference. However, it seems that the dll must be loading if other methods are working correctly. I also imported `pyarrow`.

Has anyone else encountered this problem?  I'm using Python 3.9 in Windows, polars 0.18, pyarrow 4.0.1
Any thoughts or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us a bit more code, including test data, so we can recreate the issue? If you're having to load a dll, something else seems to be going on. Why do you need `os.add_dll_directory()` at all?

Comment: Check; https://stackoverflow.com/a/72274477/8658598

Comment: your `my_df` isn't a polars dataframe but a pyarrow table. Do `my_pldf=pl.from_arrow(my_df)`

Comment: then you can do `my_pldf.to_dicts()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create dictionary of each row in polars Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75649804/create-dictionary-of-each-row-in-polars-dataframe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem was actually that I had an older version of pyarrow that does not expose the appropriate method:
[Pyarrow Table doesn't seem to have to_pylist() as a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72274138/pyarrow-table-doesnt-seem-to-have-to-pylist-as-a-method)

Upgrading to pyarrow 12.0 worked.

Thanks all!